# SHA256( from RSA Key Helper) hangs under BouncyCastle FIPS library

Tags: java, rsa, bouncycastle, entropy, fips

We moved to BC FIPS version 1.0.1 and since then RSA Key Helper hangs for extended periods of time (stack below).

We had a similar issue in Linux that was solved by increasing entropy (urandom/haveged/etc.)

Is there a similar workaround that can be employed for the Windows environment?
Our previous BouncyCastle implementation worked fine.

```
Daemon Thread [http-bio-18080-exec-10] (Suspended)  
                    owns: Object  (id=2939) 
                    owns: Boolean  (id=2940)             
                    owns: SocketWrapper<E>  (id=117)          
                    SHA2$SHA256(SHA2).implDigest(byte[], int) line: 98         
                    SHA2$SHA256(DigestBase).engineDigest(byte[], int, int) line: 181               
                    SHA2$SHA256(DigestBase).engineDigest() line: 160          
                    MessageDigest$Delegate.engineDigest() line: 592              
                    MessageDigest$Delegate(MessageDigest).digest() line: 365          
                    ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(Hashtable<String,CodeSigner[]>, Hashtable<String,CodeSigner[]>) line: 207  
                    JarVerifier.processEntry(ManifestEntryVerifier) line: 241 
                    JarVerifier.update(int, byte[], int, int, ManifestEntryVerifier) line: 228       
                    JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 482  
                    URLClassPath$JarLoader$2(Resource).getBytes() line: 124             
                    Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).defineClass(String, Resource) line: 462              
                    URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader, String, Resource) line: 73    
                    URLClassLoader$1.run() line: 368               
                    URLClassLoader$1.run() line: 362               
                    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]              
                    Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: 361       
                    Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 424            
                    Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 357              
                    BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(String, SecureRandom) line: not available            
                    BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(String) line: not available             
                    BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>() line: not available        
                    RSAKeyHelper.<init>(String, String) line: 35
```

Comment: Your stack track doesn't look like something related to entropy. If this stack trace actually represents where your code hangs, it looks like for some reasons your code handgs inside a classloader, particularly inside jar verification process. This sounds quite strange as it should be reasonably fast and determenistic process (here `SHA2$SHA256` seems to be actually `SHA256` inner class of `sun.security.provider.SHA2` from the `rt.jar`). Are you sure your stack trace is actually where the code hangs? Also, as a wild guess, don't you somehow load some of your jars over a slow network?

Comment: That is interesting! This is def one of the hanging places, the other is key generation itself. Since it is a windows vm in a corporate environment, I wonder if somehow the storage where the JRE sits has some wild latency going on, or maybe the AV software is holding the class a bit longer...I will check on Monday!

Comment: Could be a circular dependency/circular initialization issue - as in you are loading SHA-X implementation from a JAR signed by the same SHA-X algo.

Comment: Would a circular dependency unlock after a few minutes though?

Comment: Which JVM implementation are you using and which version?

Comment: Sun JVM 1.8u112